# How can I open multiple files at the same time in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I'm trying to open multiple ".csv" files but it keeps outputting "OSError: rec_11.csv not found"(actual file doesn't matter. It always stops at 3). I know the file is there and I can open it by itself. The first two files are opened fine and I can get the data but it always stops at the third one no matter what files I put in there. From what I have found this is supposed to work but it doesn't:

```
def extract(file):
    data =np.genfromtxt(file,delimiter=",")
    arr = data.transpose()
    return arr[2]

directory = r'C:\Users\...\Desktop\senior\Peeps'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        print(os.path.join(subdir, file))
        if(file.endswith(".csv")):
            people.append(os.path.join(subdir, file))
            ecg_data.append(extract(file))
```

I have also tried this:

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        print(filename)
        if(filename.endswith(".csv")):
            ecg_data.append(extract(filename))
            people.append(filename)
```

I should note that inside Peeps there are multiple folders and inside those are the csv files.

**Resolved**. It was pointed out to me that I need to join the directory and the file. The following works for me now.

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        if(file.endswith(".csv")):
            people.append(os.path.join(subdir, file))
            ecg_data.append(extract(os.path.join(subdir, file)))
```

Comment: Do you need to join the directory and filename before you pass the filename to `extract`? -> `ecg_data.append(extract(os.path.join(subdir, file)))`

Comment: Did you try to open just the 3rd file? Does it always return not *found error*?

Comment: @IainShelvington That was it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
path=os.getcwd() # Obtains your current working directory
path_list = []
valid__extensions = [".csv"] #specify your vaild extensions here
valid_extensions = [item.lower() for item in valid_extensions]
for file in os.listdir(path):
    extension = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
    if extension.lower() not in valid_extensions:
        continue
    path_list.append(os.path.join(path, file))

for csv_file in path_list:
# add what ever function you like to your .csv file
```